# nodejs & react: render another HTML file upon request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement amp pages in our project.

So far I have come to the following solution: if there is a query in the url, like: `myurl.com?amp=1`, the page is completely redrawn under the necessary markup. The problem is that at the moment, our server is configured so that it selects between 2 html files, if the error is, then the markup with an error, and if not, then the usual index. It works like this:

```
yield this.render('index', {
        state: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(state)),
        body: renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...props}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    });
```

and error

```
app.use(isProduction ? function * error(next) { // error handler
    try {
        yield next;
        if (this.response.status === 404 && !this.response.body) {
            this.throw(404);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        const STATUS_CODES = require('http').STATUS_CODES;
        const seo = require('app/modules/seo').initialState;

        this.status = err.status = err.status || 500;
        if (err instanceof URIError) {
            this.redirect('/search');
            return;
        }
        err.message = STATUS_CODES[this.status];
        this.app.emit('error', err, this);

        yield this.render('error', {
            assets,
            err,
            seo: {...seo, long_title: `${err.status} – ${seo.long_title}`}
        });
    }
} : error());
```

```
componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.isAmp) {
            document.write(expotedAmpMarkup(this.props.body))
        };
}
```

Tell me, please, how on the server side to disable the use of standard markup when there is a request in the URL?

Is it possible to make the drawing of a new page take place on the server side?

I apologize in advance for the confused text. I know too little to build a competent question, and I have no one to ask for help, except to this forum.

If necessary, it is ready to send the entire server and webpack configurations.
Ready to answer any questions. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You can render any page you need, on SSR, depending on your request.

You can take a look on my SSR app that handles routes:
https://github.com/tornado1979/ssr-rentalcars .

Some key points are below:

**client side 'index.js':**

```
.....
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config'

import store from './store'
import Routes from './components/Router/routes'


ReactDOM.hydrate(
<Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
  </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

**client side 'routes.js', here you put all your pages**

```
export default [
{
  ...App,
  routes: [
   {
     ...HomePage,
     description: "Compare car hire deals and find the cheapest prices in.",
    keywords: 'car hire, cheap car hire, car rental uk,  rent a car, car rentals, uk car car, cheap car rentals spain, cheap car rental usa, carrentals, rent car, car hire comparison, carrental, carhire, compare car hire, car rental comparison, rentalcars, rental cars',
    path: '/home',
    title: '.......',
  },
  {
    ...About,
    description: 'About Compare car hire deals...',
    keywords: 'car hire, ...',
    path: '/about',
    title: 'About - Rentalcars',
  },
  {
    ...NotFoundPage,
    description: '',
    keywords: '',
    title: 'page not found - Rentalcars',
  },
],
 },
  ]
```

**server side, 'index.js'**
*You receive the requests and send the right component to the client*
     //you need this router:
       `import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config'`

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore()
   // Initialize and load data into the store
   const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path).map(({ route }) => {
    return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null
  })

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  const context = {}
  const content = renderer(req, store, context)

  if (context.notFound) {
    res.status(404)
  }

  return res.send(content)
 }).catch(error => res.status(500).send(`Internal Server Error:, 
${error}`))
})
```

**render the `page` and `store` and pass them on client 'render.js'**

```
export default (req, store, context = {}) => {
const content = renderToString(
<Provider store={store}>
  <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.path}>
    <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
  </StaticRouter>
</Provider>,
```

)
     const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()

return (
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()}>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}
      </head>
     <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()}>
       <div id="root">${content}</div>
       <script>
         window.INITIAL_STATE = ${serialize(store.getState())}
       </script>
       <script src="bundle.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>`
  )
}

I hope it helps.